# Socket io Client connection on http Only

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

My socket io server does not have ssl certificate, so it only works in htpp, on
the other hand I have my web page which has ssl certificate,

So when I'm connecting to my socket web server (in http) on this page (in https), it's changes automatically in https so necessarily I get an error

The connection :

```
//Here I'm connecting in http
const socket = io("http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:XXXX",{secure:false})
```

here you have the pictures which illustrates the problem, i have write "http: // xxxxxxxx" and in the console i got the error:

```
 //But in the error we see that change and it's try to connect with https
 "GET https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:XXXX/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NFiqorQ   
 net :: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
```

PS: when i try to connect to the websocket with wamp (so in http) it's work...

if anyone knows how to force the connection to http, please help me

[Client side error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDpDv.png)
[Client side conection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRGIR.png)

Answer (score 0):

im sure it has something to do with your server. i only work with nginx so i can just talk about that but im sure its something similar in apache. I create virtual server blocks in nginx one is for the fileserver where ssl and certificate is enabled. after that i set up a block for the socket and set the server just to listen to http.

```
upstream socket {

server 127.0.0.1:2095;

server 127.0.0.1:80 backup;

keepalive 15;

}


server {
    
listen 80;
    
listen [::]:80;
    
        
   
root /var/www/socket/;
..... and so on
```

i work with a subdomain always to connect the socket like socket.domain.com but its not needed.

the same but with ssl on and linking certificate i do for the fileserver and this way it works pretty well.

```
var HOST = '144.125.....';
const socket = io(HOST,{secure:true})
```